# what is axios.delete correct syntax?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am performing a delete request with axios but I do not understand why these 2 syntax work differently.
After a big struggle i found this working solution by testing through postman

```
deleteChart(id) {
  const data = JSON.stringify({ id: id });

  const config = {
    method: 'delete',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/deleteChart',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: data,
  };

return axios(config)
  .then((res) => {
    return res.data;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  }
}
```

Below is what I was trying to do since the beginning but with no success, the req.body in the back end was a empty object.

```
deleteChart(id) {
  return axios
    .delete(`${API_URL}deleteChart`, {
      id,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
}
```

I have also tried to use `{data: {id}}` instead of just `{id}`, I have tried to add the `headers` object...all with no luck.

What is the difference between the two syntax?

Comment: Have you compared the requests they make via your browser's network inspector?

Comment: they are different, the first is ok response, the second one not
But what's the syntax problem?

Comment: So if you add the `const data = JSON.stringify({ id: id });` line in the second function, and change the second parameter to `{ data }` it still doesn't work? We'll also need a more specific description than "first is ok response, the second one not" (you'll have to show the requests, not just say if they're ok or not.)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Your function should be:

```js
deleteChart(id) {
  return axios
    .delete(`${API_URL}deleteChart`, {
      data: {id: id},
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
}
```

From: https://github.com/axios/axios

`axios.delete` prototype:

```js
delete<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
```

Where `AxiosRequestConfig` is:

```js
interface AxiosRequestConfig {
  url?: string;
  method?: Method;
  baseURL?: string;
  transformRequest?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  transformResponse?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  headers?: any;
  params?: any;
  paramsSerializer?: (params: any) => string;
  data?: any;
  timeout?: number;
  timeoutErrorMessage?: string;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  adapter?: AxiosAdapter;
  auth?: AxiosBasicCredentials;
  responseType?: ResponseType;
  xsrfCookieName?: string;
  xsrfHeaderName?: string;
  onUploadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  onDownloadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  maxContentLength?: number;
  validateStatus?: (status: number) => boolean;
  maxRedirects?: number;
  socketPath?: string | null;
  httpAgent?: any;
  httpsAgent?: any;
  proxy?: AxiosProxyConfig | false;
  cancelToken?: CancelToken;
}
```

So you need to pass the data in the body as inside `data` property in the config object.